# Python KS test - why is the P Value so large

Tags: python

I am trying to run the KS test for two graphs
One is the raw data plot(red), and the other is the power law fit

[image]

```
from scipy import stats
stats.ks_2samp(Red.Y, Blue.Y)
```

where Red.Y is the y value at each point of x, and Blue.Y is the power law y value at each of x.

```
Out[210]:
Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.16666666666666669, pvalue=0.99133252540492101)
```

it seems like the p value is extremely large as the graphs are not alike. May I ask the reason?

the values for Red.Y is:

```
(0.03, 0.09]    0.000018
(0.09, 0.16]    0.000019
(0.16, 0.29]    0.000016
(0.29, 0.5]     0.000018
(0.5, 0.77]     0.000018
(0.77, 1.0]     0.000022
(1.0, 1.05]     0.000021
(1.05, 1.5]     0.000022
(1.5, 2.0]      0.000025
(2.0, 3.0]      0.000025
(3.0, 4.0]      0.000024
(4.0, 6.42]     0.000026
```

the values of Blue.Y is:

```
(0.03, 0.09]    0.000017
(0.09, 0.16]    0.000017
(0.16, 0.29]    0.000018
(0.29, 0.5]     0.000019
(0.5, 0.77]     0.000020
(0.77, 1.0]     0.000021
(1.0, 1.05]     0.000021
(1.05, 1.5]     0.000022
(1.5, 2.0]      0.000023
(2.0, 3.0]      0.000024
(3.0, 4.0]      0.000025
(4.0, 6.42]     0.000026
```

Comment: It seems to me that value from red curve can be drawn from the same distribution from blue curve. KS-test is used to measure if 2 samples are from the same distribution or not. In this case, they are from the same distribution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, if I try the same method for different raw data (red curve) and its corresponding power law line of best fit (blue curve), the P value can be as low as below 0.3. May I ask the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, in KS-test, you want to compare 2 cumulative distribution (CDF) of 2 data samples [(see from from Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test). Suppose, you have blue-line data and red-line data

```
red_line = [0.000018, 0.000019, 0.000016, 
 0.000018, 0.000018, 0.000022, 
 0.000021, 0.000022, 0.000025, 
 0.000025, 0.000024, 0.000026]

blue_line = [0.000017, 0.000017, 0.000018, 
 0.000019, 0.000020, 0.000021,
 0.000021, 0.000022, 0.000023, 
 0.000024, 0.000025, 0.000026]

n1 = len(red_line)
n2 = len(blue_line)

# CDF of red line
cdf1 = np.searchsorted(red_line, red_line + blue_line, side='right') / (1.0*len(red_line))
# CDF of blue line
cdf2 = np.searchsorted(blue_line, red_line + blue_line, side='right') / (1.0*len(blue_line))

# D-statistic
d = np.max(np.absolute(cdf1 - cdf2))
```

the D statistic (first value return) is the maximum distance between 2 CDFs.

For p-value, it is calculated by multiplying this CDF difference with Brownian bridge distribution. You can see how they calculate [from the source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.1/scipy/stats/stats.py#L4745-L4760). Basically, if you compare difference between CDF with the distribution and it is still similar, we are going to get `p > 0.1` for example (means you cannot reject that they are not from the same distribution).

```
from scipy.stats import distributions

en = np.sqrt(n1 * n2 / float(n1 + n2))
prob = distributions.kstwobign.sf((en + 0.12 + 0.11 / en) * d) # p-value
```

From the given data here, I got `(D, p) = (0.1667, 0.9913)`.

So yeah, even graph looks different, when you plot CDF of 2 samples, it can be very similar and that's why p-value is still large.

Comment: can you help with how to plot like the figure comparing two cdf? Thank you